# student music arrangements

Tags: copyright, music, education

Can a student create an arrangement or medley of music compositions for an assignment(not shared publicly) without needing permission from the composer? If the student gives credit to the original composer in their composition and the arrangement is not shared with anyone but the teacher, I do not think this is a violation in any way.

Comment: Trivially, if the copyright on the source material has already expired, there's no infringement.  Of course, you're probably asking about the other possibility :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://copyrightalliance.org/education/copyright-law-explained/limitations-on-a-copyright-owners-rights/fair-use-exceptions-copyright/

> The copyright law identifies certain types of uses, including
> criticism, comment, news reporting, ***teaching, scholarship,*** and
> research as examples of activities that may qualify as a fair use.

As part of education, limited use of a copyrighted work generally falls under a fair use exception.

Acknowledging the original composer is not *legally* required. In an academic setting, however, failing to properly cite the original work is likely plagiarism, and would have academic repercussions.